# android, what is the benefit of depending on aar file

Tags: android, android-library, aar

In android app/lib it could depend on other libs

```
implementation "xxx.yyy.lib-name:{$libVersion}")
```

but it could also do

```
implementation files('libs/file-name.aar')
```

which using the generated/published `aar` file (download to local folder, or refer to maven site)

Question:

What is the benefit of depending on `aar`, or what is the use case it should be depending on the `aar`?

Comment: Is your question regarding, what the benefits of a dependency on a local library is, or just what the benefit of an `aar` lib is?

Comment: would like to know what is the case it should use dependency on the `aar` file.